# Accurate list of Gedolim

Tags: rabbis

Wikepedia's list is missing certain Gedolim. Where can I access a list of Gedolim that would be virtually unarguable?

Comment: Since when have Jews agreed on anything?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13000/759 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13039/759

Comment: I've closed this as it "will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion": the good version of this question already exists, at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13000.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/

Comment: Where can I find Wikipedia's list of Gedolim?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rabbis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Virtually unarguable?  God Himself is called "Gadol" by King David in Psalm [145:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16366#v=3).  To this day, I don't think anyone would disagree on that one.

> גדול יהוה ומהלל מאד ולגדלתו אין חקר
>
> The Lord is great and very much praised, and His greatness cannot be searched.

(*Chabad.org translation*)

Comment: I quoted this answer here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4626923#4626923