# Is it permitted for a Ben-Noach be an atheist?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, heresy, noachide-laws

Avoda zarah is one of the things prohibited by the Seven Noachide Laws. But what about atheism? I know that the 7 Laws are often taken to include a larger number of halachot from the Torah, so would the prohibition against avoda zarah expand to include kefira as well?

Comment: A followup question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28250

Comment: Too many gods, wrong. Too few wrong again.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rav Moshe Feinstein, in a *t'shuva* about allowing children to say a generic prayer in public school ([*Orach Chayim* II #24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=197)), refers to the Ramba"m's statement in *Mishne Torah* that *Adam Harishon* was given 6 commandments, including belief in God. No'ach and his descendants later got one more, adding up to 7. They both conclude that not only the negative aspect of believing in God is necessary - i.e. not serving other deities - but also the positive affirmation of His creation and provenance over the world, when circumstances call for it. Rav Moshe also uses the inference from the words of Ramba"m explained in @Yishai's answer.

Answer (score 17):

Given the Rambam's [statement](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam.asp?tDate=2/27/2012):

> Anyone who accepts upon himself the fulfillment of these seven mitzvot and is precise in their observance is considered one of 'the pious among the gentiles' and will merit a share in the world to come.
>
> This applies only when he accepts them and fulfills them because the Holy One, blessed be He, commanded them in the Torah and informed us through Moses, our teacher, that Noah's descendants had been commanded to fulfill them previously.
>
> However, if he fulfills them out of intellectual conviction, he is not a resident alien, nor of 'the pious among the gentiles,' nor of their wise men.

It would seem that the answer is no, it is not permitted.

Comment: This may be true, as long as we read the last part as saying "**nor** of their wise men"(**ולא** מחכמיהם), as it is in most printed edition, which the translation used in this answer is based on. But if we rely on the majority of Yemenite manuscripts( like [here](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e508.htm#14)) that have the last part saying "**but** of their wise men"(**אלא** מחכמיהם), then one might still ask: What if one accepts the 7 laws out of an intellectual conviction, that does not include recognition of God, is he permitted to be an atheist?

Comment: Even according to that version, they still don't merit a share in the world to come (as they are not "of 'the pious among the gentiles'").

Comment: Well, **Fred** [disagreed with me](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/will-a-non-jew-who-did-not-keep-the-noachide-laws-be-held-accountable/20541#comment48544_20541) when I made the same claim you are making( see the revision history for my answer there). He makes a good point. Also, see [**b a**'s answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20537/1368), which says a Gentile cannot excuse himself from the 7 Laws, because he can come to know them through intellectual investigation.

Comment: @TamirEvan, I don't really follow. Intellectually, someone can figure out there is a Creator, that Moshe was Given the Torah and in it are commandments for non-Jews. I don't see how that point changes the question of atheism.

Comment: (1) It does, because once you say there is an obligation to reach the 7 laws through intellectual investigation, and the laws themselves don't include belief in God, why can't one be an atheist( not being of 'the pious among Gentiles' not withstanding)? (2) Just because one "can figure out there is  a Creator...", doesn't necessarily mean one has to.

Comment: Belief in G-d is foundational to the 7 Mitzvos, it need not be enumerated as one of them, and one can't believe that they were given by G-d and Sinai (also not one of the 7), if one rejects the existence of the Giver. See also the many who object to the Rambam's inclusion of a requirement to believe in G-d as one of the 613 Mitzvos.

Comment: (1) Who says "belief in God is foundational to the 7 Mitzvot"? shouldn't the answer to that be[ part of] your answer? (2) My contention is that, **based on the source you quoted**, one need not accept that the 7 laws were given by God at Sinai in order to accept their obligation to obey them. (3) If you're basing yourself on those who are selective about what of the Rambam's they accept, maybe you should cite or quote them, rather than the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: 1. The Rambam. "This applies only when he accepts them and fulfills them because the Holy One, blessed be He, commanded them in the Torah and informed us through Moses." 2. I don't really argue with that point, just that since such a person has no place in the world to come, it shows that that isn't enough. 3. I bring that to show the thinking: How can there be a commandment to believe in the Commander when you have to accept a Commander before you can accept the commandment? It demonstrates the foundational aspect of the concept.

Comment: (1) As I have said above, one who "fulfills them out of intellectual conviction"( and contrasted with the fist half of the _Halakhah_, that means **not** through accepting Torah from Sinai) is not explicitly denied "a share in the world to come". (2) The word "only" in that quote is the translator's. It's not in the original, and in context may only refer to one being "considered one of 'the pious among the gentiles'"( and maybe one's eligibility for becoming a resident alien).

Comment: Re: belief in God not needing to be an explicit law: That may be all very well for the 613 _Mitzvot_ we are commanded. Why need that apply to the 7 Noachide laws non-Jews are commanded, that don't command an active relationship with God( like the [positive commandments](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901694/jewish/Part-1.htm) 2 through 9 of ours)?

Comment: @TamirEvan, One who fulfills them out of intellectual conviction is not from the rightous of the gentiles. That means he doesn't get the portion in the world to come. There is nothing which says the two aren't linked. It wouldn't even make sense - he gets a portion in the world to come, but isn't allowed to live in Israel? The world "only" is implied in the statement (otherwise it is a non-statement) even if the translator added the word.

Comment: Re: belief in G-d, the point is it can't be an explicit law, as it supersedes it. The answers for the Rambam's position focus on the requirement in the law being to believe something more about the Creator than simply His existence. In any event, none of the 7 laws are positive in nature, there may well exist additional positive requirements.

Comment: (1) "[N]othing which says the two aren't linked" does not mean they are.( Also, see my second comment above.) (2) Being "allowed to live in Israel" could require accepting "_Torah Min ha-Shamayim_" as a form of accepting Rabbinical authority( beyond the stated laws), but to get a portion in the world to come it would be enough to just follow the laws( regardless of justification). (3) Without the "only", the statement gives **one** situation where situation applies, but there may be others( i.e. "this applies when ... [this also also applies when]"). Using "only" excludes any other situation.

Comment: Re: belief in God: My point is that without a positive command towards God, we can't imply an underlying requirement to believe in God, like we can for the 613 we are commanded. It could be there is one, but it could be there isn't one.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not going to decide the correct version, as this is a well traveled discussion. I don't think the answer changes, whichever version you use, as [I wrote](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18628/is-it-permitted-for-a-ben-noach-be-an-atheist/18634?noredirect=1#comment80751_18634)

Comment: @Yishai I think that the conclusion is correct but this can't be the source. Rav Meir Twersky is convinced (and has convinced me) that the Rambam's opinion cannot possibly be as it is stated here. I'll try to find an online shiur where he goes through his many proofs to this

Comment: @Yishai See *Igros Moshe* ([OC II §25](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=196)), who makes the point that this Rambam implies an overarching requirement for non-Jews to believe in HaShem. However, I think the "אלא מחכמיהם" emendation lends more credence to the notion that someone who observes the Seven Laws (possibly even including monotheistic belief) not out of a belief that they were divinely commanded may still be able to earn a share in the World to Come (though, unlike *chasidei 'umos ha'olam*, they are not automatically guaranteed such a share via the 7 Laws).

Comment: @Fred, I think אלא מכחמיהם is a thin reed to hang an idea of there being more than חסדי עומות העולם in those qualified for עולם הבא. I don't know that the Rambam indicates such a concept anywhere.

Comment: @Yishai I'm not suggesting that they would be in the same category as חסידי עומות העולם, who are entitled to a share by default. Also, I'm not basing this idea mainly on "אלא מכחמיהם". The Mishna's omission of non-Jews (as a class) from those excluded from עוה"ב (a list that includes Bil'am, the people of S'dom, and the *dor hamabbul*) may suggest this (*Sanhedrin* 10:2-3). In fact, this is the conclusion of the gemara (*Sanhedrin* 105a, "מתניתין מני רבי יהושע היא"; see Rashi, s.v. מאי נינהו, who appears to go beyond the Rambam and says the non-wicked among the nations are entitled to עוה"ב).

Comment: @Fred, those examples would be more compelling if they were after מתן תורה. Even Bil'am is kind of an exception, given his level of prophecy, even if he lived during Mattan Torah. Either way, it doesn't seem that the Rambam agrees with the Rashi you cite.

Comment: @Yishai Interestingly, see Rashi ([*Sanhedrin* 96b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=96b&format=text), s.v. גר תושב), who appears to follow R' Meir ([*'Avoda Zara* 64b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=64b&format=text)) that rejecting *'avoda zara* is sufficient to become a *ger toshav* (unlike the Rambam, [*Hil M'lachim* 8:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=8&halocha=10), who seems to follow the Chachamim).

Comment: @Fred Many (most?) Rishonim go like this, including Rambam himself in SHM.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I'm aware, just about every posek assumes that all nations are obligated to believe in God in some way or another. This is stated explicitly by Rav Shmuel ben Hofni Gaon (commentary to Beraishis 34:12), Rabbeinu Nissim Gaon ([intro to Talmud](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14308_7.pdf)), probably the opinion of the Sefer Hachinuch (commandment 417, and Minchas Chinuch there), Maharal (Gevuros Hashem ch. 66, in his comparison between murder and the denial of God), Maharatz Chajes (Kuntres Achron published in the end of [Minchas Kanaos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/43015)), the Chazon Ish (Y.D. 62:20), R. Yaakov Kamenetsky (Emes L'Yaakov Beraishis 8:22), R. Moshe Feinstein (O.C. II:24), R. Reuvain Margolios (Margolios Hayam Sanhedrin 56a #25) and R. Ahron Lichtenstein ("Seven Laws of Noah" pg 78).

Most of the above assume that this is the case either because there needs to be an underlying philosophy behind keeping the seven commandments (see Rambam Hil. Melachim ch. 8), as part of the prohibition of idolatry, or because it is included in the restriction against blasphemy (this is stated explicitly by R. Margolios and R. Lichtenstein).

However, there is, as far as I know, one posek who disagrees: R. Moshe Shternbach. He writes in Teshuvos Vehanhagos 3:264 and 3:317 that non-Jews are not obligated in believing in God, as this is only obligated for (and perhaps the only difference between them and) geirei toshav.

Comment: Hello, is there a chance to read more about Rav Moshe Shternbach's reasoning in English?I am very interested on the intellectual level

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123813/rav-moshe-sternbuchs-position-on-the-belief-in-hashem-for-gentiles?noredirect=1#comment408658_123813

Comment: @Yishai https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/123933/5083

Answer (score 2):

I am an Italian ben Noach.

In my opinion, the question must be analyzed on two different levels.

The first concerns the application of Noahide Law by a human court: from this point of view, Rav Sternbuch points out very correctly that the prohibition against idolatry requires Gentiles simply to refrain from worshiping any entity other than HaShem; therefore, an atheist who does not perform acts of worship towards idols cannot be held legally responsible, by a court of justice, for having violated this prohibition. Again on the juridical level, it also does not seem to me to be disputable that an atheist is in a position to observe the other six Noahide precepts, including in my opinion the respect of the prohibition of blasphemy, a crime whose perpetration is not determined, before a court of justice, from the simple belief in the non-existence of the Almighty.

The second plan instead concerns the divine judgment towards the atheist Gentile: if he does not commit acts punishable by an earthly court under the Noahide Law, will he or will not have a part in the world to come?

On this aspect, it seems to me that the sources of the Jewish Tradition, despite their laconicity, exclude the possibility for the atheist of such participation.

In the Gemara [Sanhedrin 105a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.105a?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) it is said that those Gentiles "*who forget the Almighty"* have not a  share in the world to come.
Now, it seems very difficult to me to think that an atheist, who believes in the non-existence of HaShem, can be excluded form  those who "forget  the Almighty".

As for Rambam, his position appears to me even more clear in the direction of an exclusion of the atheist from the world to come. It is true, in Mishneh Torah-Hilchot Melachim 8: 11, according to the authoritative version of the Yemeni manuscripts, Maimonides defines "wise Gentiles" the non-Jews who observe Noahide Law out of rational conviction and not because they believe that these precepts have been revealed. by HaShem.
However, regardless of the condition of these "wise Gentiles" after their death, it seems to me to be totally excluded that Rambam would consider possible for an atheist to assume the status of a "wise man".

In Mishneh Torah- [Hilchot Yesodei haTorah 1:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904960/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-One.htm)  Maimonides in fact says that:

*"The foundation of all foundations and the pillar of wisdom is to know that there is a Primary Being who brought into being all existence. All the beings of the heavens, the earth, and what is between them came into existence only from the truth of His being ".*

And furthermore, in Mishneh Torah- [Hilchot Teshuvah 3:6-7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911896/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Three.htm), Rambam states that:

*"The following individuals do not have a portion in the world to come. Rather, their [souls] are cut off and they are judged for their great wickedness and sins, forever:
the Minim;
(...)
Five individuals are described as Minim:
a) one who says there is no God nor ruler of the world
(....)*

Answer (score -2):

"Ben Noach" as defined by Sanhedrin 56a refers to all non-Jewish humanity, to Gentiles on a whole. The seven commandments that all Gentiles are commanded to keep are the law of judgements, and prohibitions against cursing God's name, worshipping idols, forbidden sexual partners, murder, theft and eating meat taken from an animal while it's alive. According to the Talmud, all the commandments are prohibitions, only prohibitions being counted amongst the seven except one, the law of judgments which is the only one to have an active and prohibitive quality (Sanhedrin 58b-59a).

The seven commandments concern actions that a court can judge, not beliefs. And according to the Talmud, Maimonides and Sefer haChinuch, breaking any of the seven laws brings the liability of death. Sanhedrin 57a says "their warning is the death sentence" and "a child of Noah is executed for the violation of the seven laws". Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings and Wars, chapter 9 law 14 states that "A gentile who transgresses any one of these seven commands shall be executed." Sefer hachinuch, law/section 26, states, "And there is yet another difference – as when the nations transgress one of their [seven] commandments, they are always liable for the death penalty."

Based on the prohibitive qualities of the law against idolatry, the fact that the laws govern actions and not belief, and the fact that breaking one of the seven laws brings the liability of death in a righteous court, it is clear that belief in, acknowledgement of, fear of and recognition of God is not one of the seven laws. A person does not get the liability of death for not acknowledging the existence of God.

Therefore, atheism is permissible for Gentiles ("bnei noach).

This is not about whether it is morally important to accept the truth of God's existence. It's not about whether there may be some moral obligation (not divine obligation or seven law obligation) to know that God is. The fact is that the seven laws do not forbid atheism for Gentiles at all.

Unfortunately it is too enticing for those who know of the divine commandments for Jews to mix them up with the innately different set of divine commandments that Gentiles must keep.

Comment: Can you cite any of your sources? Where do the Talmud, Rambam, and Sefer HaChinuch make these claims? Where do you see from there that your conclusion is correct?

Comment: Yes, I can cite the sources. Sanhedrin 57a says "their warning is the death sentence" and "a child of Noah is executed for the violation of the seven laws". Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings and Wars, chapter 9 law 14 states that "A gentile who transgresses any one of these seven commands shall be executed." Sefer hachinuch, law/section 26, states, "And there is yet another difference – as when the nations transgress one of their [seven] commandments, they are always liable for the death penalty." Having cited the sources, the conclusion is clear that breaking one of the seven is a capital offence.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to include all relevant information. I just noticed that you’re new here, so you might not be used to the way this site works; why don’t you take a look at our [tour] for a brief overview when you have a spare minute?

Comment: Thank you. I have done what you suggested.

Comment: https://talisinwonderland.com/2011/04/06/rav-kook-on-holy-gentiles/   I report in this link the extremely interesting opinion of Rav Kook, according to which the status of the "Wise Gentiles" described by Rambam is even higher than the status of the "Righteous among the Nations".

Comment: @LoneGentile I agree with you at 100%

Comment: @Amos74 thanx for saying that

Comment: Just because something cannot be enforced by a court does not mean it is not obligatory.