# What is the fate of non-Jews in the afterlife?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws, afterlife

From what I've read before, according to Jewish belief, if a non-Jew follows the Noahide Laws, he/she will not suffer in the afterlife. Are there any verses in the Torah/Tanakh to support this?

If anything, I may have seen a verse in the Tanakh which said something like "Believe in the Lord and the prophets...". I don't remember the exact verse. But I don't know. Maybe this law only applies to Jews.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20528

Answer (score 2):

The Talmud (Sanhedrin 105a) understands from Psalms 9:18 "*Return...to the depths [of Hell] all the nations **that forget God***" that only the wicked among the nations descend there, while all other non-Jews are rewarded in the afterlife.

Comment: but don't people only stay in gehennom for a maximum of 12 months?

Comment: @EzraHoerster As a general rule, yes, but there are exceptions. I don't know what the Gemara cited above means by 'wicked', but maybe it would fit into one of those categories of exceptions.