# 7 laws of Noach - Tinnok Shenishbah

Tags: reward-punishment, noachide-laws

I know in Judaism, we have a concept of "Tinok Shenishba" - does this not apply to a gentile? How will a ben noach at the end of time be punished for not keeping the 7 mitzvah bnei Noach if they are simply not aware of it?

Comment: Related: "[Will A Non Jew who did not keep the Noachide Laws be Held Accountable](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20528/1368)"?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I don't think so: (a) The question here is more about whether the term _Tinoq she-Nishbah_ applies to Noachides (with the subject of the other question being a ramification), and (b) neither the question there, nor the existing answers, presently  address the idea of a Noachide _Tinoq she-Nishbah_.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rambam (Melachim 10):

> "A gentile who inadvertently violates one of his commandments is exempt from all punishment with the exception of a person who kills inadvertently. ...
>   When does the above apply? When he inadvertently violates a command without sinful intention; for example, a person who engages in relations with his colleague's wife under the impression that she is his own wife or unmarried.
>   If, however, one knew that she was his colleague's wife, but did not know that she was forbidden to him or it occurred to him that this act was permitted or one killed without knowing that it is forbidden to kill, **he is considered close to having sinned intentionally and is executed**. This is not considered as an inadvertent violation. For he should have learned the obligations incumbent upon him and did not."