# Does a Goy raised among non-sheva-mitzvos-observant Goyim have the status of a "Tinok shenishba?

Tags: gentiles, noachide-laws

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92144/is-there-a-status-of-tinok-shenishba-for-non-jews?noredirect=1#comment299735_92144):

Does a non-Jew who was raised by other non-Jews who do not keep the sheva mitzvos of Bnei Noach, the 7 Noahide commandments, have the status of a "tinok shenishba" as far as his obligation to keep the sheva mitzvos of Bnei Noach is concerned?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88775/7-laws-of-noach-tinnok-shenishbah