# What happens to a non-Jew in the afterlife?

Tags: gentiles

Suppose you were born on an island where you have never met a jew in your entire life, where you have never seen a synagogue before, never seen a rabbi before.

What happens to your soul, if you are ignorant of judiasm, never even having heard of the word Judaism, never been taught to pray?

Comment: Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/will-a-non-jew-who-did-not-keep-the-noachide-laws-be-held-accountable

Comment: @Josh, thank you for helpful answers.

Comment: Rita welcome to Mi Yodeya. Just to provide some context, Judaisim is not a "universalist" religion. We do not believe that non-Jews are obligated to follow the laws Jews are bound by, or that you cannot live a just, full life without being Jewish, nor that you need to be Jewish to get into heaven. For more information on what Judaisim has to offer non-Jews, click here  https://www.aish.com/w/nj/For_Non-Jews.html?mobile=yes