# Prayer and the Noahide/Gentile

Tags: halacha, tefilla, noahidism

I know that Noahides have their own siddur and are not bound or obligated to pray, but could one (a Noahide) pray the actual Amhidah for example and omit the words "our" or anything that connects them with actual ties to the Israelites and the Patriarchs of the Jewish people?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40554/what-exactly-do-noahides-do

Comment: They have their own siddur?

Comment: Yeah http://www.amazon.com/Prayers-Blessings-Principles-Service-Noahides/dp/0981481132

Comment: From a noahide source was heard that yes.

Answer (score 2):

AskNoah created a Noahide version of the Amidah:
https://asknoah.org/forum/showthread.php?tid=25

```
A Noahide Amidah (Copyright '09 by Ask Noah International)

Blessed are You, G-d, the Supreme Being Who bestows abundant kindness.
Please endow us graciously with wisdom, understanding and knowledge.
Please accept our repentance, and forgive us for our errors and sins.
Grant complete healing for all our wounds and ailments.
Bestow upon us all the needs for our sustenance from Your bounty.
Hasten the day of which it is said, "G-d will be King over the entire earth; in that day G-d shall be One and His Name One" [1]; "For then I will turn the peoples to pure language, so that all will call upon the Name of G-d to serve Him with one purpose," [2] and "They will not harm or destroy on all My holy mountain, for the earth will be filled with knowledge of G-d as water covering the sea bed." [3]
Hear our voice, G-d, our merciful Father, have compassion upon us and accept our prayers in mercy and favor. Blessed are You, G-d, Who hears prayer.

[1] Zechariah 14:9
[2] Zephaniah 3:9
[3] Isaiah 11:9
```

As a Noahide, I find it difficult to pray the Amidah and many of the prayers as found in the Jewish siddurs. It's very easy to make false statements in prayer while trying to change the words on the fly. For organized or corporate prayer, there are several Noahide siddurs.

1. Noahide Nations
   https://noahidenations.tech/store/index.php?route=product/product&language=en-gb&product_id=30
2. AskNoah
   https://asknoah.org/asknoah_resource/prayers-blessings-principles-of-faith-and-divine-service-for-noahides
3. Oklahoma B'nai Noah Society (downloadable for free)
   https://okbns.org/Free.html
4. Noahide World Center (downloadable for $6)
   https://noahideworldcenter.org/products/brit-olam-prayer-book-for-noahides-by-rabbi-oury-cherki

Some people like to pray from the Psalms.
- Psalm 139 to know your path
- Psalms 16, 32, 41, 42, 59, 77, 90, 105, 137, 150 general remedy, especially for depression
- Psalm 133 peace in the home

Another option is hitbodedut - or personal prayer.
A great book on personal prayer is called "In Forest Fields" by Rabbi Shalom Arush, translated by Rabbi Lazer Brody.
https://breslev.com/product/in-forest-fields-the-garden-of-prayer-and-hitbodedut-english/

He also wrote, "The Universal Garden of Emuna" which also talks about Noahides and prayer.
https://breslev.com/product/the-universal-garden-of-emuna-buy-just-one-book-campaign/