# is idolatry one of the noachide laws? there is a discrepancy between websites

Tags: avodah-zarah, noachide-laws

is idolatry one of the noachide laws?  there is a discrepancy between websites.

wikipedia says

The seven Noahide laws as traditionally enumerated are:

> ```
> Do not deny God.
> Do not blaspheme God.
> Do not murder.
> Do not engage in illicit sexual relations.
> Do not steal.
> Do not eat of a live animal.
> Establish courts/legal system to ensure obedience to the law.
> ```

Whereas another link http://www.keepingtheseven.com/seven-noahide-laws/  lists idolatry as one of them

> ```
> Prohibition of Idolatry
> Prohibition of Blasphemy
> Prohibition of Murder
> Prohibition of Theft
> Prohibition of Sexual Immorality
> Prohibition of eating flesh taken from an animal while it is still alive
> Establish courts of justice
> ```

Another link http://www.gotquestions.org/Noahide-laws.html   equates "do not deny god", with no idolatry.

IIRC DoubleAA was of the view that idolatry was in the noahide laws on every or almost any link online, and I managed to find some with some without, but those comments seem to have gotten deleted, both his and mine, and i'm unable to recover that information. But the above suffices for examples.

The question though, is what is correct.. Is Idolatry in the noahide laws, or not?  Please include references.

Comment: I must say I hadn't checked every website. I just assumed the majority would have the accurate information. Idolatry is definitely one of the 7.

Comment: Re: difference between idolatry and denying God, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48957/5083

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The source for these laws is traditional from *Chazal*, and they explicitly list them in [Sanhedrin 56a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%90):

> תנו רבנן שבע מצות נצטוו בני נח דינין וברכת השם ע"ז גילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים וגזל ואבר מן החי
>   
> **[Translation:](http://www.halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_56.html)** Our Rabbis taught: seven precepts were the sons of Noah commanded: social laws; to refrain from blasphemy, idolatry; adultery; bloodshed; robbery; and eating flesh cut from a living animal.

So *avoda zara* - idolatry, is explicitly stated as one of the laws. I guess one could think of idolatry as denial of Hashem, but the specific law listed is idolatry.

By the way, even [Wikipedia's source](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/The_Seven_Noahide_Laws.html) later on mentions the first law as "The prohibition of idolatry". I don't know why they changed the words.. but they too think of it as one and the same.

Comment: Thanks. I get the words sheva mitzvot and bnai noach, but those aside, can you translate each of those words?

Comment: @barlop Sure, I pasted the translation from halakhah.com. The "ע"ז" part is "עבודה זרה" = idulatry.