Universalism and Olam Haba
I know Chabad generally maintains that all Jews will end up in Olam Haba and will be rewarded after tehiyas hameisim—even those Jews who committed major sins. I am wondering if there are any sources that expand this vision of universal salvation to non-Jews. It seems unfair, for example, to exclude from Olam Haba non-Jews who are atheists if they behave morally and are merely misled intellectually.

Chabad didn't invent כל ישראל יש להם חלק לעולם הבא.

I am aware. But the Mishna proceeds to enumerate some exceptions. Chabad is unique in arguing that even people in those categories will be readers in some form: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2312388/jewish/Chapter-5-Who-Will-Rise.htm. Correct me, though, if I’ve misunderstood and this idea too extends back further than Chabad.

Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18628/6592

Welcome to MiYodeya Yerachmiel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

In this question we see that the Gemara has a list of specific Jews and non Jews who have no Olam Habah. This would imply that everyone else, Jewish and not, does receive Olam Habah
No Olam Habah for these?

The Mishna specifically says כל ישראל. If you're referring to בלעם, it's just saying he wasn't a righteous gentile (see Bartenura, Meiri). That doesn't mean everyone else is by default, especially if we're talking about heretics.

Where is your proof that this list is meant to be complete?
