# What blessing would one have said on seeing Einstein for example?

Tags: blessing, rabbis, science

The [Oruch Hashulchan O Ch 224, 6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%93) says

> הרואה חכם מחכמי ישראל שגדול בתורה מברך: "ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם
>   שחלק מחכמתו ליריאיו,
>
> Someone who sees a Jewish Torah sage makes the blessing “ שחלק מחכמתו
>   ליריאיו"

and later he says

> הרואה חכם **מחכמיהם** הגדול בשארי חכמות מברך: "ברוך... שנתן מחכמתו לבשר
>   ודם
>
> Someone who sees a non-Jewish wise man with wisdom in other fields
>   makes the blessing שנתן מחכמתו לבשר ודם

What about the blessing for a Jewish wise man with wisdom in other fields?

Comment: Related questions: [Who is worthy of reciting the blessing “שנתן מחכמתו לבשר ודם” on?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16642/who-is-worthy-of-reciting-the-blessing-%d7%a9%d7%a0%d7%aa%d7%9f-%d7%9e%d7%97%d7%9b%d7%9e%d7%aa%d7%95-%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%a9%d7%a8-%d7%95%d7%93%d7%9d-on), [Upon whom would one make this blessing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/upon-whom-would-one-make-this-blessing)

Comment: I think that there is a chiduh of Rav Yitschack Hutner that there is no blessing, but this is strange

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/10-15-18/

Comment: I found the mare makom in a forum בפחד יצחק חנוכה מאמר ט' דווקא כתב להדיא שאין מברכין על חכמות חיצוניות של חכם מישראל. דייק כן בפשיטות מלשון הגמרא שיש רק מציאות של חכם אוה"ע בחכמה חיצונית וחכם ישראל בחכמת התורה. וביאר שם לפי דרכו הבדל בין הקשר הנפשי של שבע מצוות בני נח למקיימיהם (קשר של סמיכות דעת) לבין תרי"ג מצוות (קשר של יצירה). החלוקה שלו דווקא נראית רלוונטית לדיון שלפנינו.

Comment: I asked a similar question in my bet midrash a year or so ago. One individual answered without a source, that the principal basis of the aforementioned blessing is to 1.)acknowledge Hashem’s bestowment of that particular wisdom (Torah/worldly wisdom) to humanity 2.) upon which it is utilized to an extensive ascendant degree, and to acknowledge the greatness of the scholar in question, for their “purpose” is currently actualized.      If this answer holds any truth, then one could understand the corresponding blessings. The blessing on the Talmid Chacam exists to laud a Jew who fulfills [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] his potential, meaning that if he possesses other wisdom and is without Torah, he has not achieved his purpose. As by the Non-Jew, who’s purpose is to strive for wisdom in worldly matters, he has achieved his purpose. This remains unsourced, b”h hopefully I’ll find the guy and/or his source.

Comment: @Yaakov you still need the extra assumption that no Jew has a purpose of being really smart at a non-Torah subject. I have no reason to accept that assumption. Some Jews are really good at medicine and using that to save lives is seemingly their purpose in life.

Comment: @kouty Your two references are good enough for two answers!

Comment: Yes but I have not the book and generally am not able to understand Rav Hutner Sichot

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I heard the same as you (can't remember the source, sorry) with the explanation that a Jew who has achieved greatness in secular subjects, it is a misuse of the gifts Hashem gave him (which should have been used for Torah), and we don't make a bracha on something which is a stira to ratzon Hashem.

Comment: The words "שגדול בתורה" and "הגדול בשארי חכמות" are additions of the Arukh haShulchan. All older sources just say חכם מחכמי ישראל and חכמי אומות העולם. There is no indication it matters what any of them are wise in so long as they are indeed wise. And that fits with the blessing text.