# Mekubal in New York

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, mysticism-kabbalah, chutz-laaretz

I am looking for an authenticated mekubal in New York who is also a Torah scholar and can assist me with a pressing personal issue.

Comment: I can understand why you would want a Torah scholar to help you out, but what do you need a mekubal for?

Comment: Close as subset of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13753/759 ?

Comment: I would like to see someone with mystical insight not derived from the wrong source.

Comment: Rav Gedalia Schorr in Boro Park is a not only someone who is prolific in Chassidus and machshava be is also a talmid chacham of great stature

Comment: I think that you should talk to your local rabbi or someone who knows you. Answers and guidance for personal issues are ..very...
. personal.
I cant understand how a mekubal could be able to suddenly solve a years-long problem just after hearing a one minute summary of it.

Comment: Yaakov, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I think that this is a valid request for a recommendation, since it includes enough specific criteria ("authenticated mekubal," location, "Torah scholar," willing and able to help people with personal issues) to be answered and evaluated objectively. That said, it would be even more answerable if you'd [edit] in more details of what you mean by "authenticated mekubal."

Comment: Some advice I heard from a Rosh Yeshiva: Avoid those "mekubalim" who take money or do "weird" things. I wish you success in dealing with this issue...

Comment: why not call Rabbi Yaakov Hillel in israel

Comment: The reason I am seeking a genuine Mekubal is because I not getting what I need where I live and I am visiting New York quite soon. Surely there is a Mekubal in this largest Jewish community outside of Israel?

Comment: I heard a saying once in a Lithuanian Yeshiva that goes something like this: "It is hard to determine who is an authenticated Mekubal, but if someone openly talks about Kabala it's a sign he is not one of them".

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95788/170