# Disagreeing with one's rebbe

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, rabbis, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

We all have Rabbeim that we ask questions to.

Is one allowed to disagree with his *rebbe* if he feels that his rebbe's viewpoint is incorrect?

Comment: If you already know the answer, why are you asking in the first place? If you don't know the answer, how can you disagree?

Comment: CYLOR :) (15 char)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman But what if you don't agree with what he says? ;)

Comment: @Daniel As they say: wash, rinse, repeat...

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12874

Comment: You may "disagree" with his opinion but if you ask if something is permitted and he tells you it is not, you should not do it. If it's a recurring issue you might seek other Rabbinic authorities but don't do it right now. If he tells you it's permitted you are potentially allowed to be Chumra and refrain from doing whatever if it doesn't impact on others.

Comment: Halachic/Hashkafik or "Chol" questions (where to work, to buy a house or not)?

Answer (score 2):

R. Reuven Leuchter Shlita often says (and infers from R. Y. Salanter's responses to his student in Or Yisrael) that a rebbi is to present the relative merits of different courses of action; not to choose for you.

Comment: Is that referring to advice and guidance in general (e.g. what city to move to, what career to choose, etc.), or even deciding an overtly halachic question (e.g. "Some milk fell into my pot - is it kosher?").

Comment: He made it clear that he wasnt talking about halacha.  He contrasted halacha where the point is only the destination; reaching the correct conclusion, with broader avodah where (part of) the point is the journey; making the decisions.  Passing off the decision is thus forfeiting the whole thing.